# Active Job with Rails 4 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-activejob, devise-async

I am trying to set up Active Job with Rails 4 and Devise. I'm open to any tutorial, if there is any (couldn't find through my searching.)

I know there is a [Devise Async gem](https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async), but it does not cover Active Job in it. That said, I found [this gem](https://github.com/ushu/devise-async-activejob) that is fresh in development, but I'm getting an `uninitialized constant Devise::Async::Backend::Base (NameError)`error. (Could be me being airy on implementing it).

Any suggestions are welcomed. I'm hoping I don't have to create new controller methods.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can include the following code in your desired model (normally `User`):

```
def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
end
```

You can take a look at the following page for more detail: http://www.sitepoint.com/devise-authentication-in-depth/

Comment: This appears to be the officially recommended technique now in Devise's README: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#activejob-integration

Comment: hmmm... I take it half-back. As per https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3550#issuecomment-94248927 (and the method comments https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/2f0002a449a8b9616d51127dc6247bfd8414523d/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L123), it could be more complicated than this if you're using built-in devise notifications on user creation. `deliver_later` probably only works for previously saved records, not new records.

Comment: Thanks guys for being active on this. I gave you guys the points since your answer is better than what I ended up going with.